# Как правильно хранить временные данные?

Tags: python

Пишу телеграм бота. Есть многоуровневое меню. В каждом меню есть переменные, которые я хочу хранить. В последнем пункте меню я хочу аккумилировать данные и отправить в чат, а потом очистить эту "таблицу". Подскажите самый простой вариант для хранения таких данных. В каждом меню эти данные разные, поэтому не хочу использовать обычные БД.

```
Telegram_user_id:
    fio
    data
    ..
```

Вот пример одного из меню

```
def ZakazatPropusk(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    text = message.text
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Введите ФИО.', reply_markup=hideBoard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, GetFio)

def GetFio(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Укажите дату.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, GetData)
```

Comment: почему бы просто не хранить их в списке или словаре?

Comment: @Viktorov ну мне нужно организовать поиск по списку еще организовать

Comment: Хорошо. А словарь чем не подходит?

Comment: @Viktorov мне нужен готовый враппер. Чтобы я могу dict[user_id]["value1"]=2; примерно такого плана операции делать

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону defaultict или dataclass, может быть их хватит

Comment: @Viktorov а они threadsafe?

Comment: а не знаю. Я предложил несколько вариантов, дальше вам придется самостоятельно понять, подходят ли они вам. Я еще только изучаю Python)

Answer (score 1):

Почему вас не устроит следующий алгоритм:

```
my_data = dict()
# меню 1
my_data["fio"] = "<any fio>"
# меню 2
my_data["data"] = "<any data>"
# меню итог
pack_to_chat(**my_data)
del my_data
```

По пользователям - ну как-то так можно, основная идея "запихать" всё в словарь:

```
users = [{"name": "user1", "group": "admin"}, {"name": "user2", "group": "viewer"}]
data = {"admin": {"..": ".."}, "viewer": {}}

for user in users:
    send(data[user["group"]], user["name"])
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Это телеграм бот, и там должен быть у каждого юзера свой dict. Вы правильно поняли мою мысль, реализация тоже корректная. А как сделать разделение по юзерам?

Comment: обновил ответ - добавил пример - в зависимости от того какой группе принадлежит пользователь он получает разное сообщение

Comment: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-user--and-chat-related-data  вот тут то что мне нужно, но у меня pytelgrambotapi

Comment: в примере реализовано, что есть словарь user_data - в котором по id хранятся пользовательские данные `all = {"user_id1": {"fio": "..", "messages": []}, ..}`

Comment: Эт понятно) а как мне thread-safe dict создать?

Comment: с потоками нужно аккуратно... можно использовать общий словарь при условии что не будет изменения одних и тех же значений - один ключ - один поток